# Access HABTM join table records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, join, many-to-many, rails-console

I have a HABTM relation in my application like this:

```
class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :authors
end

class Author < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :books
end
```

In rails console I can access the records of Book and Author like this:

```
Book.all
Book.first
b = Book.first
b.title = "Title2"
b.save
...
```

But I don't know how to access the join table.

How can I access and see the records in the join table `books_authors`?

Is is possible to change the join table rows?

Comment: You can't. `has_and_belongs_to_many` uses a join _table_, not a join _model_. You want to use `has_many :through` with a join model.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to access the join table records, you'll have to recreate this with a `has-many-through` relationship. There's a great guide to doing this, and the differences between `has-many-through` and `has-and-belongs-to-many`, here: http://railscasts.com/episodes/47-two-many-to-many.

You'll need to create a new migration like the following to create the join table:

```
class Authorships < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :authorships do |t|
      t.belongs_to :book, index: true
      t.belongs_to :author, index: true

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
    add_foreign_key :authorships, :books
    add_foreign_key :authorships, :authors
  end
end
```

where 'Authorships' can be any name you deem suitable for the join table (or 'BookAuthors' if you'd want to stick with that).

As a quick example, your models could look like the following:

```
class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :authorships
  has_many :authors, through: :authorships
end

class Author < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :authorships
  has_many :books, through: :authorships
end

class Authorship < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :book
  belongs_to :author
end
```

You can add extra columns to the join table and access them as needed, along with `authorship_ids`, and `Author.first.books` / `Book.first.authors` once they're added.

Hope that's useful!